# Symfony finder component does not work properly

Tags: php, file, symfony, finder

I try to get list of files in my `web` directory with `Finder` component.
But component does not work properly.

I try this:

```
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->in('web/images/avatars');
```

But I have an error

> "The \"web/images/avatars\" directory does not exist."

It's weird, cause I have similar code in my `Console Component` command and it works well

Then I tried that code

```php
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->in(__DIR__ . '/../../../../../web/images/avatars');
```

It's work, but it return an empty array

I checked that directory for permission to read, all fine

And if this will be usefull, I try to do this in my `User Provider`

Comment: are you sure it isn't just a relative path issue, have you tried using the absolute path?

Comment: it isn't a path issue, i checked this million times. With absolute path is the same story

Answer (score 0):

The `__DIR__` refers to the directory that the file is in - presumably somewhere deep inside your src/ directory, hence the requirements to get back out and then into the web directory itself.

If the command works from the command line, but not when run from a website, then the issue is likely one of file permissions - under Apache on Ubuntu for example, files are run as user `www-data`, and may not have full access to read, or write files (or, as importantly, the entire tree of directories, to be able to read the list of files within the directory).

Comment: I'm thinking about it, but as I noted above, this folder has full permissions to read